# Getting configurePhpcs is not callable after update drupal to 8.3.2

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I updated drupal with composer `composer update`

Drupal is updated to 8.3.2 but when I install modules I get anytime this message

`Method Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::configurePhpcs is not callable, can not call post-auto  load-dump script`

how to make configurePhpcs callable again?

[image]
Website is still working,

Comment: Have you solved you issue? Having the same error here...

Comment: Nope, still struggling

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that after the Drupal core update, you've overwritten composer.json with your previous settings.

However, in Drupal 8.3.2, configurePhpcs has been deleted. This part of composer.json (around line 69 has to be changed:

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::configurePhpcs"
    ],
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
},
```

You have to delete configurePhpcs line (and the comma at the end of the line above, so it should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
    ],
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
},
```

Then, you won't see the message anymore.

Comment: Yes, but what if you want to use PHPCS still?